# JavaScript + jQuery create an object with different variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, variables

My goal is to create an object with some variables that I can access later.

My Created Object

```
var object = {
variable1: "test",
variable2: document.getElementById("cb").options[document.getElementById("cb").selectedIndex].text
}
```

However, I get an error message with variable2

> Index:2817 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'text')
> at Index:2817

I have also tried:

```
variable2: $('#cb option:selected').text()
```

that did not work. I would like to understand why? And how can I avoid this error or solve the problem efficiently?

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You likely call your script before the select exists

Comment: @mplungjan If that were the problem it would says that you can't access the `options` property.

Comment: I suspect you're doing this before any options have been added to the select.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `selectedIndex` until the user selects something from the dropdown.

Comment: Make it a function that returns that value when you call it

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, that was the problem.